# displaying Pandas DataFrame in HTML without the extra row

Tags: python, html, pandas

If I use `DataFrame.set_index`, I get this result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['foo',1,3.0],['bar',2,2.9],
                   ['baz',4,2.85],['quux',3,2.82]],
                 columns=['name','order','gpa'])
df.set_index('name')
```

[image]

Note the unnecessary row... I know it does this because it reserves the upper left cell for the column title, but I don't care about it, and it makes my table look somewhat unprofessional if I use it in a presentation.

If I don't use `DataFrame.set_index`, the extra row is gone, but I get numeric row indices, which I don't want:

[image]

If I use `to_html(index=False)` then I solve those problems, but the first column isn't bold:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML

df = pd.DataFrame([['foo',1,3.0],['bar',2,2.9],
                   ['baz',4,2.85],['quux',3,2.82]],
                 columns=['name','order','gpa'])
HTML(df.to_html(index=False))
```

[image]

If I want to control styling to make the names boldface, I guess I could use the new [`Styler` API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#style) via `HTML(df.style.do_something_here().render())` but I can't figure out how to achieve the `index=False` functionality.

What's a hacker to do? (besides construct the HTML myself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I poked around in the [source for Styler](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cc3daa6f7e140e870d57c3b02a5d2142e11d09c9/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L335) and figured it out; if you set `df.index.names = [None]` then this suppresses the "extra" row (along with the column header that I don't really care about):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['foo',1,3.0],['bar',2,2.9],
                   ['baz',4,2.85],['quux',3,2.82]],
                 columns=['name','order','gpa'])
df = df.set_index('name')
df.index.names = [None]
df
```

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what this does, however. :/

Comment: thank you, this is useful in general. It simply removes the index name... (I noticed the extra row sometimes in outputs, and was also puzzled what it means.)

Answer (score 3):

These days pandas actually has a keyword for this:

```
df.to_html(index_names=False)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html